# get parent activity in fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I am working with the Facebook SDK and I am facing a Problem. The FacebookLoginFragment is overlaying my Login Activity. In fact, I kind of know the answer why it is, but I'm working now for hours on a solution.

I need the view in the onCreateView method, but if I inflate it, it is just an overlay to my activity_login. How can i **get the correct view without inflating** it?

Please see the code below.

#### Login extends FragmentActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //get editText Views
    editTextlogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_login);
    editTextpasswd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_passwd);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new FacebookLoginFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
    } else {
        // or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (FacebookLoginFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }

}
```

#### FacebookLoginFragment extends Fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    con = new FacebookConnection();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);

    // The results of the authentication are returned to the activity, to
    // get the Fragment to receive it
    // call the setFragment() method
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
            .findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    if (Session.getActiveSession().isClosed()) {
        authButton.setReadPermissions("user_status", "email", "publish_actions");
    }

    return view;
}
```

#### activity_login

(I know the relative layout isn't best practice, it was just for testing)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="at.ts_company.activity.Login" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/primary_material_light" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/login_loginname"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_passwd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText_login"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/login_passwd" 
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/final_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_createAccount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
    android:text="@string/login_createAccount" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="register"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText_passwd"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow_right"
    android:text="@string/login_loginbutton" 
    android:onClick="login"/>

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView_createAccount"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_passwd"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />
```

Comment: post `activity_login.xml` please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have to answer my own question.

It was not that easy as I thought, and it's not the solution I had in mind.

I have added the functionality in the Fragment (FacebookLoginFragment), and in the Login.java I just call the Fragment.

I had to delete the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)` in the Login, and add all the functionality, except the if-statement to the Fragment.

I defined the onClick Method for my button in the Login.xml, therefore i have a Method `login(View view)` in my Login.java, which just calls the `fragment.login(View view)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but why not access it via a static instance?

```
private static MyActivity Instance; 
public static MyActivity getInstance() {  return Instance; }
```

And in the `onCreate` method, you assign the activity to Instance `Instance = this;`
But be sure to check if the returned instance isn't `null`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, we finished the project a year ago so I'm not working on it anymore but your answer seems quite simple, I think this would work though I had no time to test it.

Comment: I believe you. I'm using this to access stuff i want. I hope it'll be usefull for other people facing similar problems :)